# Getting duplicate data based on dynamic key

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Person objects:

```
List<PersonData> AllPersons
```

From this list I want all those person objects that are duplicated based on a certain property.

Example, this code give all the duplicates based on the Id

```
var duplicateKeys = AllPersons.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).Where(x => x.Count > 1).ToList().Select(d => d.Key);
    duplicates =  AllPersons.Where(p => duplicateKeys.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
```

Can the part p.Id be dynamic?

Meaning if the user specifies the unique column in a config file and it's read like so:

```
string uniqueColumn = "FirstName";
```

How can the query be composed to add that functionality?

Regards.

Comment: What `AllCompanies` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection to achieve that:

```
List<PersonData> AllPersons = new List<PersonData>()
{
    new PersonData { Id = 1, FirstName = "Tom" },
    new PersonData { Id = 2, FirstName = "Jon" },
    new PersonData { Id = 3, FirstName = "Tom" }
};

string uniqueColumn = "FirstName";

var prop = typeof(PersonData).GetProperty(uniqueColumn);

var duplicateKeys = AllPersons.GroupBy(p => prop.GetValue(p, null))
                              .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                              .Where(x => x.Count > 1)
                              .Select(d => d.Key)
                              .ToList();

var duplicates = AllPersons.Where(p => duplicateKeys.Contains(prop.GetValue(p, null))).ToList();
```

`duplicates` have 2 elements with `FirstName == "Tom"` after query execution.

Comment: p => prop.GetValue(prop, null) gives "Object does not match target type" error. Any idea?

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry for that mistake.

Comment: WOW. Simply amazing. You made my day. Thanks Marcin for your help and appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) or [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).